# Getting permission issue for vendor mage folder while update anything on admin

Tags: magento2.3.2, file-permissions

I am using magento 2.3.2 community edition. While update any setting at backend I am getting error like

> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/var/www/html/ihouzit/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---39a_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/html/ihouzit/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 691

Sometimes to mage MysqlPDO file. 
Why this happens lot of times. Always I run permission command, then it comes in normal. Any fix solution for this issue?

Same error for bellow file also

> var/cache//mage-tags/mage---39a_DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL): failed to open
>   stream

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please set default Magento file and directory permissions

Comment: yes I have set 777 for vendor and cache folder

Comment: Please follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions).

Comment: I have set , but it reoccur again again..this is the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set permission 777 to your var, generated and pub folder.

```
chmod -R 777 pub/*;
chmod -R 777 var/*;
chmod -R 777 generated;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two more thread discussing same question [#thread1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141545/error-warning-file-put-contents-var-www-html-var-cache-mage-tags-mage-792-c) [#thread2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198239/magento-2-permission-denied-with-colinmollenhour-module-cache).

First i run permission on the necessary folders. Please [visit this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions) for Magento necessary folder permission

After permission i found that the website is on 2 language English and Spanish.

When i run content deploy code

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

It is only write en_EN folder and not write in another folder es_ES. So i got the exact code this to write pub/static folder

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US es_ES -f

And i got the solution.